# how to build a 16 bits RAM with 1 data register and a U-bus? (using Logisim)

Tags: ram, cpu-registers

Using LOGISIM, build a working 4-nibble RAM. The RAM must have the following elements: 4 nibbles, addressing circuits, the address register, the data register, the mode register (bit), a u-bus, and a clock. Your RAM must be able to read and write nibbles.

You will run your circuit manually by setting the address, mode and data registers, then you will start the clock. The desired action will take place. For example: if you plug in an address into the address register, and a 1 in the mode register, and a nibble in the data register, and you turn on the clock, then the nibble must be copied into the RAM nibble at the desired address.
Since you have a 4-nibble RAM then you will only have addresses 00, 01, 10, and 11. Mode register set to 1 is for write and 0 is for read.

A u-bus is needed to properly handle read and write operations between the data register and the 4-nibbles of RAM.

Elements allowed:
Connectors: 
- Wires 
- Input connector 
- Output connector (or display)

Built-in machines and gates: 
- A Bit (RS, or D) 
- Clock 
- AND, OR, NOT, XOR, NAND, NOR